# caption in the html output of knitr

Tags: html, r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

When knitting the following `Rmd` file

````
```{r, fig.cap="mycaption"}
plot(0,0,axes=FALSE,xlab=NA,ylab=NA)

```
````

with the "Knit HTML" button of RStudio then the caption does not appear in the html output file. Indeed the html source code corresponding to the figure is:

```
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,..." alt="mycaption"/></p>
```

To see the caption it should be for instance:

```
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,..." alt="mycaption"/><p class="caption">mycaption</p></p>
```

How to easily get an html output with visible captions ?

Comment: if you convert md to html through Pandoc, you will get a visible caption; otherwise you may need to redefine the [`plot` hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks), and I'll leave it to other people to answer you

Comment: I noticed something strange when I looked at the resulting html of my answer, it looks like the paste is wrapped in the code blocks' own `<p>` even though it's supposed to be after the block. Yihui, is that expected behaviour?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I usually just use `results='asis'` in the chunk options and include raw html in the chunk, wrapping it in `cat()` but as Yihui mentioned you can create your own hook:

````
```{r}
knit_hooks$set(htmlcap = function(before, options, envir) {
  if(!before) {
    paste('<p class="caption">',options$htmlcap,"</p>",sep="")
    }
    })
```

```{r, htmlcap="Hello Dolly"}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds,aes(price,carat)) + geom_point()
```
````